# Redirection and Regex in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have recently visited by Google Search Console just to discover that when I was updating my site back in 2011 that I have previously used a different type of permalinks withing WordPress thus creating over 500 404 errors.

Now I installed the plugin called "Redirections" for WordPress and tried to get rid of the 404 errors with simple ragex commands but it seems I am doing something wrong.

My old link looks like this:
`http://www.example.com/category/blog_domain/2011/02/random-title-inserted-here/`
New links are like this:
`http://www.example.com/random-title-inserted-here/`

So I inputted this under source url: `/([A-Za-z_0-9-]*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)`
And this under target: `/$5``

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else looking for an answer to this:

Source: `^/category/blog_domain/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/$`

Target: `/$3`